# Is there a context free, non-regular language $L$, for which $L^*$ is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, regular-languages

I know that there are non-regular languages, so that $L^*$ is regular, but all examples I can find are context-sensitive but not context free.

In case there are none how do you prove it?

Comment: Can be answered with the same techniques as http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/

Comment: Hint: all languages which contain the alphabet have a very simple Kleene closure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$L = \{a^n b^n \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is context-free but not regular (classical example). So is $L' = \{a^n b^n \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\} \cup \{a,b\}$.

$L'^\ast = \{a,b\}^\ast$ is regular.

Comment: Brute-force, but valid.

Comment: $L' = L$, actually...

Comment: @vonbrand ... actually not.